# Converting a date object into a date string

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to convert a date object into a string that SQL Server will understand.  This is what I have so far:

```
(function() {
    Date.prototype.MMDDYYYY = function() {
        var month, day, year;
        month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length === 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(this.getDate());
        if (day.length === 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        year = String(this.getFullYear());
        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }
})();

(function() {
    Date.prototype.HHMMSS = function() {
        var hour, minute, second;
        hour = String(this.getHours());
        minute = String(this.getMinutes());
        second = String(this.getSeconds());
        return '' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
    }
})();


function DateTimeFormat(objDate) {
    return objDate.MMDDYYYY() + ' ' + objDate.HHMMSS();
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
Object Tue Jan 29 ... (Eastern Standard Time) has no method MMDDYYYY.

It might be obvious, but I don't understand how to prototype.
Using jQuery is acceptable.

Comment: are you sure that you pass a date to `DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: @Pointy Where do you see checking `.length` on a number?

Comment: @Ian in my imagination apparently :-)

Comment: @Pointy Haha I know what you were thinking/meant, I wasn't sure if I was crazy or something!

Comment: @Phillip how exactly are you *calling* your "DateTimeFormat" function?

Comment: I'm rewriting it now to also be in the prototype.

Comment: @Phillip when I try your code as-is, and call `DateTimeFormat(new Date)` it works fine

Comment: Yeah, my mistake was I was passing in a string instead of date object.  I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a string to the function `DateTimeFormat`.

You can ensure it's a date object by adding this...

```
objDate = new Date(objDate)
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference? The functions don't need access to any external symbols.

Comment: Because in the example they only exist inside the anonymous functions, so DateTimeFormat cannot call them.

Comment: Dang it!  objDate is a string!  I thought for sure I made it a Date object!  How do you make it a Date object?

Comment: Just wrap it with a date object... `objDate = new Date(objDate)`

Comment: @Archer but the functions are assigned directly to properties on `Date.prototype`.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I sent @Archer on a bit of a goose chase because the argument was a string instead of a date object.  So sorry!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the real problem. Putting them in IIFEs technically doesn't do anything special or help in this scenario, but doesn't hurt

Comment: I'll edit the answer to my above comment instead, as that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem isn't scope, but how do you create the objDate! I've done a few tries, and that error come up when objDate is a String. So, this snippet of code works as expected, the problem is the parameter passed to DateTimeFormat: I think it'is created like this `objDate = Date()` instead of `objDate = new Date()`. The latter will correctly create a Date object instead of returning date in a String format.